# AngularJS - ng-show not working as intended

Tags: javascript, angularjs, passport.js

I'm trying to hide to `<a>` tags, and then show them when I'm logged in, using the `isLoggedIn()` function, but the `<a>` tag is showing no matter what.

**HTML (pool-details.html)**

```
<header class="hero-unit" id="banner" ng-include="'components/header/header.html'"></header>

<div ng-include="'components/navbar/navbar.html'"></div>

<div class="container"> <hr>
    <div class="col-md-3 left-col-3">  
        <div ng-include="'../components/sidebar/sidebar.html'"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="details-pic">
            <img class="pool-details-pic" ng-src="{{ pool.picture }}"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3 class="details-name">{{ pool.name }}</h3>
        <p class="details-info">Varenummer: {{ pool.number }}</p>
        <p class="details-info">Lager status: {{ pool.inStock }}</p>
        <p class="details-info">Dimensioner: {{ pool.width }}m x {{ pool.length }}m x {{ pool.height }}m</p>
        <hr>
        <p class="details-info">{{ pool.info }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <a ng-show="'isLoggedIn()'" ng-click="deleteProduct(pool)" class="delete-product">Slet</a>
        <a ng-show="'isLoggedIn()'" ng-click="editProduct(pool)" class="edit-product">Opdater</a>
    </div>

</div>

<footer class="footer" ng-include="'components/footer/footer.html'"></footer>
```

**CONTROLLER (pool-details.controller.js)**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('welldanaJavascriptApp')
    .controller('poolDetailsCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, $state, poolService, Auth) {

        $scope.pool = {};
        poolService.find($stateParams.poolId, function(pool) {
             $scope.pool = pool;
        });

        $scope.deleteProduct = function(product){
            poolService.delete(product._id, function(){
                $state.go('pools');   
            });
        };
});
```

I can't wrap my head around why the `<a>` tag is still showing, though I'm not logged in. I'm using the Passport plugin for an Angular fullstack application.

Comment: Where is the IsLoggedIn() function defined?

Comment: I'm wondering the same as the above comment - in addition, the ng-show should be written as ng-show="isLoggedIn()", without the single quotation marks.

Comment: The `isLoggedIn()` is a function provided by Passport. In the controller I'm using Passport by adding the `Auth`

Comment: @Fissio removing the single quotation marks, simply removes the `<a>` tag, and doesn't show when `isLoggedIn()` equals true

Comment: @Detilium Add `{{isLoggedIn()}}` somewhere in your HTML so you can see whether the function actually returns true when you'd expect.

Comment: @Fissio I can't see it anywhere, so I guess somethings wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you should assign the Passport's `isLoggedIn()` function to your scope? I.e. something like this in your controller: `$scope.isLoggedIn = Auth.isLoggedIn;` Or create a wrapper, `$scope.isLoggedIn = function () { return Auth.isLoggedIn(); };`

Comment: @Detilium That would indicate that the function `isLoggedIn` doesn't exist in the scope. Can you do a `console.log(Auth)` and inspect around if you can find the `isLoggedIn()` function somewhere in there? In that case, I'd imagine something like `$scope.isLoggedIn() = function() { return Auth.isLoggedIn() }` would work. EDIT: Exactly what the above comment says ;)

Comment: @Fissio Added my solution below. Sorry for any inconvinience

Comment: @Detilium No worries man, glad you got it sorted out :)

Answer (score 2):

```
ng-show="'isLoggedIn()'"
```

it calculates 'isLoggedIn()' string and it will always true, you should refactor as`ng-show="isLoggedIn()"`

Answer (score 0):

Okay I managed to sort out my problem. It was a simple rookie mistake from my hand, my apologies.

**Solution**

I was missing the `$scope.isLoggedIn()`

I simply addes this to the controller:

```
$scope.isLoggedIn = function(){
    return Auth.isLoggedIn();
}
```

And just returning the `Auth.isLoggedIn()` to actually add this value to my scope, thereby being able to check it in the HTML.